# Append a character to a specific location in a column in a data frame

Tags: r, concatenation, gsub

I am having a data frame like this

```
df <- data.frame(
       'Week' = c(27,28,29),
       'date' = c("2019-W (01-Jul)","2019-W (08-Jul)","2019-W (15-Jul)"))
```

I need to append Week column after **W** in date column

```
expecteddf <- data.frame(
       'Week' = c(27,28,29),
       'date' = c("2019-W27 (01-Jul)","2019-W28 (08-Jul)","2019-W29 (15-Jul)"))
```

How can I achieve this in R?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `paste0` with a combination of `sub`, i.e.

```
 paste0(sub(' .*', '', df$date), df$Week, sub('.* ', ' ', df$date))
#[1] "2019-W27 (01-Jul)" "2019-W28 (08-Jul)" "2019-W29 (15-Jul)"
```

Answer (score 2):

in base R, you could also use `regmatches` + `regexpr` check the solution [@Darren](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63359682/append-a-character-to-a-specific-location-in-a-column-in-a-data-frame/63359980#63359980) for elaboration on the pattern `(?<=W)`

```
regmatches(df$date, regexpr("(?<=W)", df$date, perl = TRUE)) <- df$Week
df
  Week              date
1   27 2019-W27 (01-Jul)
2   28 2019-W28 (08-Jul)
3   29 2019-W29 (15-Jul)
```

Answer (score 1):

With `stringr::str_replace`, the replacement can be vectorized:

```
library(stringr)

df$date = str_replace(df$date, "W", paste0("W", df$Week))
df
#   Week              date
# 1   27 2019-W27 (01-Jul)
# 2   28 2019-W28 (08-Jul)
# 3   29 2019-W29 (15-Jul)
```

---

Alternately, we could take a date formatting approach. Converting your `date` column to an actual `Date` class (`df$Date`, below), we can then convert the actual `Date` to your desired format (or any other).

```
df$Date = as.Date(df$date, format = "%Y-W (%d-%b)")
df$result = format(df$Date, format = "%Y-W%V (%d-%b)")
df
#   Week            date       Date            result
# 1   27 2019-W (01-Jul) 2019-07-01 2019-W27 (01-Jul)
# 2   28 2019-W (08-Jul) 2019-07-08 2019-W28 (08-Jul)
# 3   29 2019-W (15-Jul) 2019-07-15 2019-W29 (15-Jul)
```

Comment: You are using `%W` which starts from 00-53, you should rather use `%V` which starts from 01-53 ie `format(df$Date, format = "%Y-W%V (%d-%b)")`

Answer (score 1):

A `base` solution with `sub(..., perl = T)`:

```
within(df, date <- Vectorize(sub)("(?<=W)", Week, date, perl = T))
```

***Note:***

- *`"(?<=W)"` matches the position behind `"W"`.*
- *The first two arguments of `sub()` cannot be vectorized, so `Vectorize()` or `mapply()` are needed here.*

---

The corresponding `str_replace()` version, which is vectorized.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(date = str_replace(date, "(?<=W)", as.character(Week)))
```

---

***Output***

```
#   Week              date
# 1   27 2019-W27 (01-Jul)
# 2   28 2019-W28 (08-Jul)
# 3   29 2019-W29 (15-Jul)
```

Comment: i still took the answer from you

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using:

- `gsub` + `Vectorize`

```
expecteddf <- within(df,date <- Vectorize(gsub)("W",paste0("W",Week),date))
```

- `gsub` + `mapply`

```
expecteddf <- within(
  df,
  date <- mapply(function(x, p) gsub("(.*W)(\\s.*)", sprintf("\\1%s\\2", p), x), date, Week)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mutate in str_c

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(date = str_c(str_sub(date,1,6),
                       Week,
                       str_sub(date,7)))
```